# Примеры разработок

Tags: android, java

Многие показывают движки для 2D-3D игр, а мне хотелось бы спросить - есть ли в опенсурсе исходники таких сервисов как "такси", где есть серверная часть где то в вебе и клиентская в java или android приложениях, происходит создание заказа, изменение статусов, оплата, сообщения.

Comment: хочется пощупать, потрогать такие сервисы на предмет "как люди делают".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, такие сервисы все самописные, ибо, во-первых, ничего сложного, во-вторых, работают в связке со своими оригинальными back-end'ами. Либо вариант "все в одном" типа битрикса...

Comment: Присоединяюсь. Писал однажды биллинг, который обрабатывал заявки на авиа-жд билеты для одного тур-агентства. Ничего сложного:]